# В каких случаях стоит использовать Spring boot для прототипирования веб-приложения?

Tags: java, веб-программирование, spring

Доброго дня, уважаемые гуру разработки. Поделитесь, пожалуйста, своим опытом разработки с использованием Spring и Spring boot. Стоит ли использовать Spring boot для прототипирования веб-приложения? Встречали ли Вы случаи использования таких систем на продакшен-решениях? Какие есть минусы у такого подхода. Возможно ли в дальнейшем изъять из приложения Spring boot, оставив просто Spring или даже перейти на другой java-фреймворк? Есть ли еще какие-то адекватные способы создания прототипа для веб-приложения на java с возможностью потом нарастить функциональность в прототипе?

Answer (score 0):

Частично отвечу:
Если у вас стоит задача изъятия некой технологии из проекта в будущем, то скорее всего вы что-то делаете не так.
Не забывайте, о том, что если вы меняете одну технологию на другую, то вам нужно переписывать кусок проекта, включая тесты. Если проводилось ручное тестирование, то его тоже нужно провести по новой.

Этап выбора технологий требует внимания.